DirectoryEntry cannot find the Fritzbox entry in Workgroup
I'm trying to get a list of computers in the workgroup.
using (DirectoryEntry workgroup = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://WEBDEVEL")) 
{      
    Debug.WriteLine(workgroup.Name);     

    foreach (DirectoryEntry child in workgroup.Children)     
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(child.Name);     
    }
}

Two computers are listed in Windows Explorer.

R-W1-W11
WD-FB-FOS

When I run the code it only outputs R-W1-W11 and schema. I have checked all the necessary settings. Until recently this code worked fine.
Why is this code no longer listing all the entries is a mystery to me.
Maybe someone here has an idea.
I tried to find another way to get the full list. Unfortunately without success.
Otherwise, the app works perfectly with the Fritzbox elsewhere (copying files into the share)
